# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.lwjgl.DefaultSysImplementation.getPointerSize()I

Tags: java, exception, linker, unsatisfiedlinkerror

At first this looks like a duplicate of like 9 other questions, but mine is actually unique. And no amount of answers have fixed it. Working with JLWGL.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:     org.lwjgl.DefaultSysImplementation.getPointerSize()I
    at org.lwjgl.DefaultSysImplementation.getPointerSize(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:113)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:135)
    at renderEngine.DisplayManager.createDisplay(DisplayManager.java:30)
    at engineTester.MainGameLoop.main(MainGameLoop.java:11)
```

No amount of googling has revealed the cause. I have followed several tutorials to the letter. The natives folder IS PROPERLY SET UP. Yes I still get this bug! Sooo frustrating!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue today when trying to run a Slick2D application. The issue came up, I think, because I used two different versions of LWJGL. Using Maven, Slick2D came with a dependency to LWJGL 2.9.1 while the natives I provided already came from 3.0. So I downloaded the 2.9.1 natives which solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was solved by reverting to the latest LWJGL 2 build. The libraries I was using are not yet compatible with LWJGL 3.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only thing it could be is your natives. You said the natives folder is properly set up: did you actually delete and replace all of the *.dll files?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and for me it was I think just putting the .dll files contained in the SlickSet native-windows.jar in the root of my project file. (http://wiki.netbeans.org/SlickSet number 5)