# My code for using the "minecraft-launcher-lib" to create a simpler launcher keeps throwing an error

Tags: java, python, minecraft

I'm trying to make a Minecraft launcher that will always open 1.8.9 in Python because I found the minecraft-launcher-lib python package and it works a lot better than using batch in my opinion. It works really well with 1.14.3 - 1.16.5(which is what I've tested). The problem is I use Minecraft 1.8.9, and it keeps throwing an error with a function in LWJGL called "org.lwjgl.DefaultSysImplementation.getPointerSize()". LWJGL stands for "LightWeight Java Game Library", which is the game library Mojang uses to make Minecraft. Is there a problem with my code or can anyone explain to me and give me a fix to this problem?

Code:

```
import subprocess

#Get latest version
latest_version = minecraft_launcher_lib.utils.get_latest_version()["release"]
print(latest_version)

#Get Minecraft directory
minecraft_directory = minecraft_launcher_lib.utils.get_minecraft_directory()
print(minecraft_directory)

#Login
login_data = minecraft_launcher_lib.account.login_user(<username>,<password>)
print(login_data)

version_list = minecraft_launcher_lib.utils.get_version_list()
print(version_list)

#Get Minecraft command
options = {
    "username": login_data["selectedProfile"]["name"],
    "uuid": login_data["selectedProfile"]["id"],
    "token": login_data["accessToken"]
}
minecraft_command = minecraft_launcher_lib.command.get_minecraft_command("20w14infinite",minecraft_directory,options)
print(minecraft_command)

#Start Minecraft
subprocess.call(minecraft_command)
```

Error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.lwjgl.DefaultSysImplementation.getPointerSize()I
    at org.lwjgl.DefaultSysImplementation.getPointerSize(Native Method) ~[DefaultSysImplementation.class:?]
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:118) ~[Sys.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71386_F(Minecraft.java:2756) ~[ave.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:41) ~[Main.class:?]
    ... 6 more
[20:05:04] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]: net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.FMLSecurityManager$ExitTrappedException
[20:05:04] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:    at net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.FMLSecurityManager.checkPermission(FMLSecurityManager.java:30)
[20:05:04] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkExit(SecurityManager.java:761)
[20:05:04] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:    at java.lang.Runtime.exit(Runtime.java:107)
[20:05:04] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:    at java.lang.System.exit(System.java:973)
[20:05:04] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:138)
[20:05:04] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: It looks like you are using the wrong version of LWJGL for that Minecraft version, the older/newer versions use completely different versions of the LWJGL library. See here for another user who solved the issue by getting the correct library/dll: [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.lwjgl.DefaultSysImplementation.getPointerSize()I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27240202/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-org-lwjgl-defaultsysi)

Comment: So, this does seem like it's gonna work, but the problem is that, after some research, 1.13 and later use LWJGL 3 while 1.12 and before use LJGWL 2. This means that newer versions like 1.16 or 1.17 snapshots won't work. So, how would I make it so that newer version of Minecraft will use v3 while older versions of Minecraft will use v2? Also, can I have a little bit more clarification about what files to place where?

Comment: I'm not trying to use LWJGL for my own project, mine is made in Python. When launching Minecraft 1.8.9, it throws the error. So, when launching Minecraft, it will look in wherever the files are, so if I change the files, the newer version of Minecraft might not work.

Comment: Each version has it's own folder, but the LWJGL files aren't in there. It's saved in a different folder in the .minecraft folder. Also, LWJGL 2.9 is in the folder where all the LWJGL files are, so you would expect it to work. But for some reason, it's decided to keep throwing the error in the main post. If you've worked with Minecraft and LWJGL a while ago, then you might be used to the old file structure as a lot has changed. Most of the guides for LWJGL are really outdated. Also, the only files in the version folder is a .json and most times a .jar file for that version.

Comment: I see, double-check that your version is [2.9.4](http://ci.newdawnsoftware.com/job/LWJGL-git-dist/176/), then let's delete this comment chain and see if anyone else knows the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out what caused it to give the error. The command that was generated had 1 small error. It was trying to access some natives that don't even exist. So, I created a natives folder in the .minecraft folder and changed the incorrect path to the path of the natives.